# .trigger('click'); isn't triggering

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

```
$('a#city-prompt').fancybox({
    'width': 750
});
/*$('#city-prompt').trigger('click');*/
```

The code as is, works good, but when I trigger the click using jQuery it doesn't actually trigger anything

Comment: I'll apologize in advance for this question, but shall I assume that the `trigger` code is not commented out in your code?

Comment: haha, yes, when I uncomment it, clicking on the element does nothing, and refreshing the page does nothing.  When it's commented out I can click on the element to trigger the fancybox.

Comment: Try placing the `trigger` code in a `setTimeout`, like `setTimeout(function(){$('#city-prompt').trigger('click');},100);` Maybe the image isn't loaded, and that somehow messes things up?

Comment: Yep, good call... post it as an answer so I can give you credit ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#city-prompt').click();
```

Or:

```
$('a#city-prompt').fancybox({
  'width': 750
 }).click();
```

Comment: That isn't functionally different from `.trigger('click')`.

Comment: In theory, yes, but maybe something odd is happening here :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this ? :

```
$('#city-prompt').click(function() {
  //What you wanna do here
});
```

Comment: That would re-apply the fancybox plugin on every click.